# Elasticsearch should not operation query

Tags: elasticsearch

Say we can match 
 `("name"="A" AND "name!="B")`  as,

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","A"))
.mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","B"));
```

How can I imply a "shouldNot" operation for 
`("name"="A" OR "name"!="B")`

like,

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","A"))
    .sholdNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","B"));  // This API not exists..!
```

Comment: Have you tried `"name":"A OR -B"` ?

Comment: I was trying with boolQueries.Let me try that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","A"))
            .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","B")))
```